# So...how do I push files into a repo?

Tags: git, github

I have github repository, I have user settings all set up properly, I have ssh key generated. All I wanna do is to push files from a folder into this repository. Just once.

Sorry for posting this question here, but I'm just tired of spending hours, fighting with merge errors, automatically pushing some old files after `git push origin master` etc...

Yes, right now after using 'git push origin master' I automatically push all files from the previous git repository with the same name.

I used `git reset --hard HEAD`, did everything again, empty status, add, commit, push - and it still adds these old files.

**What is going on?** :P

EDIT:

`git clean -d -x -n` doesnt work either

`git reset --hard` - same problem

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: origin git@github.com:username/Project.git (fetch) and the same with (push).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a git repos on github and want to add a directory to it

1) clone the existing empty repos

```
git clone 'git@github.com:username/Project.git'
```

2) cd into the new directory and mkdir a new directory ie abc1

3) copy the files into the new directory

4) add the new files and the new directory

```
git add "abc1"
```

5) commit the new files and new directory to the local git copy

```
git commit -a -m "added abc1 just for fun"
```

6) push the changes back to the remote

```
git push
```

7) to check it all worked, git clone again in a completely different directory

Hope this helps!  If this isn't quite what you need to do, add more detail to your question and someone more expert than me will answer!

Comment: Acutally, what worked for me, was format C, then buying new comp...well, I just deleted .git folder and reinstalled it :D